# jquery modal popup events

Tags: jquery, popup, modal-dialog

Does anyone know how to trigger a modal from an even? Like a thank you message from a news letter subscruption form. I am using the bpopup modal and it works fine from a click action, but I need it triggered from a hidden input value in  my form. I could trigger it from the submit, but the form needs to run a check first then redirect to a thank you message. At the moment the value in the hidden input displays the link message.

Here is a link to the modal I am using: http://dinbror.dk/blog/bPopup/

Here is the form;

```
form action='http://' method='post'
input type='hidden' name='list' value='Marketing'/
input type='hidden' name='redirect-success' value='my-website.com/thank-you'/
p align="left">Join our Mailing List</p
input type='text' name='email'/
input class='radio' type='radio' name='action' value='add' checked='checked'/>Subscribe
input class='radio' type='radio' name='action' value='delete'  style="margin-left:   140px;"/>Unsubscribe
input type='submit' value='subscribe'
/form>
```

This seems to be a real challenge as know one seems to be able to do it, that i have asked so far anyway?

Answer (score 0):

There are many events you can use (i'm not sure if jQuery supports them all). However: there is the onblur event that fires every time someone takes away the mouse from your radio buttons (but it is mostly used in textareas). Then there is the onsubmit event usefull to check if the form is completed but if you need to fire the onsubmit event only then write down a function that checks if the form is completed and only then says "thank you", or "you have to complete the form!". Something like the following (without jQuery):

```
<input type='submit' value='subscribe' onsubmit="checkntnk()">

<script> function checkntnk(){
            array=getElementByTagName("form");
            check = 0;
            for (i=0; i < array.length; i++){
                if (array[i]= "checked"){
                    check=1;}
                }
            }
            if (check!=0){
                alert("Thank you");}
            else{
                alert("You have to complete the form before submitting");
            }
        }</script>
```

In place of the alert you can use your bpopup().